# How to derive the equation of a triangle in vector form?

Tags: vectors, parametric

I recently read that the equation of a triangle can be expressed in the following form:

$$\vec{r}=u\vec{r_{1}}+v\vec{r_{2}}+w\vec{r_{3}}$$

Where $$u,v,w\in [0,1]$$

How is this equation derived? Is this a generalization of the equation of the line in vector form? Can this be extended for a quadrilateral, pentagon and so on?

Comment: See barycentric co-ordinates (eg http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BarycentricCoordinates.html). You want the additional condition $u+v+w=1$. Allowing negative co-ordinates parametrises the outside of the triangle, giving the whole plane. The natural generalisation is by reference to a simplex in $n$ dimensions - there is redundancy if you have more points - like a quadrilateral in a plane, (Barycentric co-ordinates are homogeneous)

Comment: I also just found this: [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_combination). This too gives an explanation based on convexity.